# python django save string with datetime.strptime and display?

Tags: python, django

I have a string `time= "10:00AM"`

I use `strptime` convert it to datetime format

```
time = datetime.strptime(time, '%I:%M%p')
```

here is my models.py

```
time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

It show this in database:

```
1900-01-01 11:00:00+00:00
```

Is it normal??

How can I show 11:00 if I want to display on website?? 
Please teach me,thanks

I try this is not work

```
import time 
test = '1900-01-01 11:00:00+00:00'
print (time.strftime(test,"%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Comment: So all you got is a local time without a date?

Comment: Use a [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield) if all you're storing is the time (without a date).

Comment: @vikki this can be an actual answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is normal, the DateTimeField stores date AND time. In your case `1900-01-01` is the default date used when you don't supply one. Just use a [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield) if all you need to store is the time of day (without a specific date).

As for displaying:
Both of these will output `11:00 AM`

: in your template

```
{{ time_value:time "h:i A" }}
```

: printing in python

```
print my_model.time.strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

Comment: Thanks! by the way, is there any way can show ````'1900-01-01 11:00:00+00:00'```` if I want to display the format ````hour-minute```` or ````year-month````?  I look document usually use now time to explain,I don't know where to put my parameter?

Comment: @user2492364 You want to display it in your template?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`datetime.combine(date,time)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time = "10:00AM"
>>> time = datetime.strptime(time, '%I:%M%p')
>>> datetime.combine(datetime.today(), time.time())
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 10, 0)
```

- maybe if you look at the website today, there is no confusion what `11am` means.
- maybe tomorrow, or some other time, you may care that `11am` referred to another day.

Comment: please refer to the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects